# Applying a font family to a whole page doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I checked online but nothing helped me, some said use this code:

```
*{
      font-family: Verdana;
 }
```

I tried putting it in the body, head, nothing, some said instead of * to use body, tried it, didn't work. I saw if my code even worked in general, I tried to change the font of a single paragraph with a selector and it worked.

```
<body>
          *{
            font-family: Verdana;
          }

          <a class="btn btn-danger" href="http:www.yahoo.com"> what </a>
          <a class="btn btn-success"> owo </a>
           <style>
          .btn {
            font-size: 55px;
          }
          .btn-danger {
            background-color: red;
          }
          .btn-success {
            background: rgba(128, 0, 0, .25);
            font-family: fantasy;
          }
          </style>
          <p class="Cx"> blacks111 </p>
          <style>
          .Cx {
            background-color: grey

          }
          </style>
</body>
```

Comment: Style definitions must go inside `<style>` tags (preferably in the `<head>`).

Answer (score 0):

In order for your styles to work you should wrap them in a `<style></style>`, like this (it won't work otherwise):

```
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Verdana;
  }
</style>
```

When you were told to put it in body or head, they were probably talking about the css selector, not the HTML tags.

According to MDN:

> In CSS, selectors are used to target the HTML elements on our web
>   pages that we want to style.

[You can read more about CSS Selectors here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors).

Answer (score -2):

Here is the solution: 
Use !important which an overriding attribute.
HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="http:www.yahoo.com"> what </a>
      <a class="btn btn-success"> owo </a>
       <style>
      .btn {
        font-size: 55px;
      }
      .btn-danger {
        background-color: red;
      }
      .btn-success {
        background: rgba(128, 0, 0, .25);

      }
      </style>
      <p class="Cx"> blacks111 </p>
      <style>
      .Cx {
        background-color: grey

      }
      </style>
```

CSS:

```
*{
        font-family: Verdana !important;
      }
```

Comment: I tried it in the body and the head, I copy pasted it, It didn't work, i tried changing the * to body aswell, it didn't work

Comment: I don't whats the issue. It's working fine. Soon I will upload the jsFiddle link. Please wait

Comment: I got it, The * { font-family: Verdana; } needs to be inside the style tags. How simple.

Comment: Why is `!important` necessary here?